# How to increase score for each time that the User mark a radio button that has a especific class

Tags: jquery

I need to increase score of the user for each time he has marked a radio button that has the class 'jiTBkb'.

That´s what i came with:

```
                let score = 0;
                $("#submitAsw").click(function(e) {
                    $questions = $(".choice-container");
                    $as = $questions.find('input:checked')

                    $as.each(function() {
                        checkAnswers(this)
                    })

                    function checkAnswers(element) {
                        if ($as.hasClass('jiTBkb')) {
                            score++
                        } else {
                            console.log('null')
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Comment: `score` is only updated when the submit button is clicked, not when the radio button is clicked... which is probably not what you want.

Comment: you are validating a users score on the front-end? I don't know what the score is for, but this would be pretty unsafe and easy to hack if that's all the validation there is. It's also pretty easy to find out which answers are correct if you inspect the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```js
let score = 0;
let totalQuestions = 2;

$("#submitAsw").click(function(e) {
    $questions = $(".choice-container");
    let rightAnswers = $questions.find('input.jiTBkb:checked').length;
    let wrongAnswers = totalQuestions - rightAnswers;
    console.log(rightAnswers + ' - ' + wrongAnswers);
    
    if (rightAnswers === totalQuestions) {
        console.log('congrats! You rocked!')
    }
})
                
function checkAnswers(element) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('jiTBkb')) {
        score++
        console.log(score);
    } else {
        console.log('null');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice-container">
  Wrong answer <input type="radio" name="test1"> Right <input type="radio" class="jiTBkb" name="test1"><br>
  Wrong answer <input type="radio" name="test2"> Right <input type="radio" class="jiTBkb" name="test2"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submitAsw">
</div>
```

Comment: First things firt, thank you for you time! But, not exactly. The ideia was to count each time the user chose the right answer. The answers had that especificly class. I´ve changed my code a little bit...

Comment: @LucasdeCarvalho Like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a diferent code, but it worked.

```
let score = 0;
let totalQuestions = 40;
$("#submitAsw").click(function(e) {
    $questions = $(".choice-container");
    $as = $questions.find('input:checked')
    $as.not('.jiTBkb').each(function(i) {
        score++
        return
    })
    let rightAnswers = totalQuestions - score
    let wrongAnswers = totalQuestions - rightAnswers
    if (rightAnswers === totalQuestions) {
        console.log('congrats! You rocked!')
    }
    console.log(rightAnswers, wrongAnswers)
})
```